# Spring Context File Reuse with Different Properties

Tags: spring, configuration

I have a fairly straight-forward spring-integration app that polls an external FTP site, processes any found files using some internal business logic and then posts a results file via FTP.  Currently when we add a new customer, we copy the XML config file and a corresponding properties file and change a prefix on all bean definitions, bean references and properties.  We then add those to an XML config file that simply does imports for all existing customers and their properties:

```
<property-placeholder location="
    file:config/application.properties
    ,file:config/test-customer1.properties
    ,file:config/test-customer2.properties
 "/>                    
<import resource="test-customer1-context.xml" />
<import resource="test-customer2-context.xml" />
```

These xml files are identical except for a unique customer prefix in the bean names.  Seems like there must be a way for me to reuse a single XML file (or a Java Config object) with different sets of properties.  My first thought was to implement a custom CustomerScope, but I don't see how the scope implementation can know the proper customer.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?

As requested, sample of customer context file

```
<bean id="testClient1RequestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${test.client1.in.queue}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testClient1ResultsQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${test.client1.results.queue}"/>
</bean>
...
```

Comment: Please add the content of one of your files test-customer1-context.xml

Comment: I'm not sure it matters what is in the customer files, but I'll include a snippet (they are rather large).